# Table view not scrolling to top when multiple arrays use same table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am hitting a api and getting the datas and storing it in arrays. This api are hit with paginations when scrolled to end of tableview. Three arrays are maintained and they fed to the tableview based on a segment control. When a particular segment is touched then for that particular api is hit and the tableview is loaded(pagination also implemented). Like wise for three segment , three arrays are maintained and loaded into the same tableview(Used only one tableview).

Now the issue is if i scroll the tableview by clicking first segment and if touch the second segment the table view is automatically scrolled where the past one we scrolled.

I have tried scrollToTop=yes, Setcontent offset to zero and many more. But i couldnt scroll the table view everytime i load it.

What i want is whenever the segment control is touched and the tableview is loaded then it should load fully i.e it should scroll to top.

Please provide solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

consider using `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` Protocol on your tableView Class. This can help you creating a smooth scrolling experience and avoid recreating the array over and over again while interacting in it.

What the Docs tell about scrollsToTop:
*we execute this gesture only if there's one on-screen scroll view with `scrollsToTop == YES`. If more than one is found, none will be scrolled.*

There is no `TableView scrollToTop` function in TableView Class and possibly you meant the property, then it is actually part of the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

instead try the following..

```
NSIndexPath *thePath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.yourArray-1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:thePath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPositionBottom) animated:NO];
```